# python key unknown in yaml

Tags: python, key

I have the following yaml file

```
  name: somehost
  values:
    network_lo: "127.0.0.1"
    network_eth0: "10.10.10.10"
    hardwaremodel: x64
    network_eth1: "192.168.10.10"
```

I would like to fetch all network* keys / values and print there values in an single value.
Though the interfaces could have different names. So i don't know what the interface name is called. 
Normally I would do something like this:

```
with open(file, 'r') as stream:
facts = yaml.load(stream)

multiple = facts['values']['network*']

# single interface
print facts['values']['network_db_backend']
expected 

# all interfaces
print multiple
expected: 127.0.0.1, 10.10.10.10, 192.168.10.10
```

How can I go over an yaml file fetch all network interfaces and print there values into a single string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work

```
import yaml                                                                                                                            

with open('file.yaml''', 'r') as stream:                                                                                               

    facts = yaml.load(stream)                                                                                                          


    multiple = ', '.join([val for (key,val) in facts['values'].iteritems() if "network" in key])                                       
    # single interface                                                                                                                 
    print facts['values']['network_lo']                                                                                                
    # 127.0.0.1                                                                                                                        

    # all interfaces                                                                                                                   
    print multiple
```

and you can replace

```
"network" in key
```

with a regexp if you wish